# How to position back arrow button in react navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

I'm new to react-native and I was playing around with react-navigation. I have a problem with positioning of the back-arrow in the navigation tab. I would like to target the back-arrow in order to position it.

Here is what I've done so far

```js
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return { 
    headerTitle: navigation.state.params.navTitle,
    headerStyle: {
      height: '45%',
      backgroundColor: '#ffae19'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',

    // this what I tried to implement
    headerTitleStyle: { position: 'absolute', top: 10 }
  }
}
```

You see I just need to make the back-arrow positioned at the top, because in my current tab the arrow is at the center of the nav-tab (vertically), which looks ugly. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly change the style of the automatic back arrow. However, you can override the back arrow with your custom component, as explained [on React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html). The article is about right part of the bar, but as stated in the last part, the same holds for the left part of the bar, where the arrow is placed.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return { 
    headerTitle: navigation.state.params.navTitle,
    headerStyle: {
      height: '45%',
      backgroundColor: '#ffae19'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerLeft: (
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Back" />
    )
  }
}
```

If you don't like the "Back" label, you can install [react-native-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons) using npm and modify the previous code like

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return { 
    headerTitle: navigation.state.params.navTitle,
    headerStyle: {
      height: '45%',
      backgroundColor: '#ffae19'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
          style={{ /* Put your style here */}}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} >
      >
          <Icon name="md-arrow-round-back" size={16} color="#000" />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import icons

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons;
```